# I can't save a foreign key into one to many table asp.net but data can be inserted asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i have two tables aspNetUser and Tutorial i want a registered aspNetUser to to be able to create  a tutorial and i want return the tutorial data to their page and other pages but i am strugling with saving the tutorial with the aspNetUser'id, i have been looking at one to many articles but they only show how to do one to many but what i want is the code for controller or view to save the tutorial with the aspNetUser id
I would appreciate any help, here is my code below:

**Tutorial model**

```
[Table("Tutorial")]
public class Tutorial
{
    [Key]
    public int TutorialId { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Course Name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Course Name")]
    public string CoursesName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Discription is required")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

}
```

**Identity model**
i modified it like this

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public ICollection<Tutorial> Tutorials { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

and in my **Controller**
Create and edit

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "TutorialId,Topic,CoursesName,Description,Content")] Tutorial tutorial)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Tutorials.Add(tutorial);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(tutorial);
    }

    // GET: Tutorial/Edit/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Tutorial tutorial = await db.Tutorials.FindAsync(id);
        if (tutorial == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(tutorial);
    }
```

And lastly my **Create view**

```js
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Tutorial</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Topic, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Topic, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Topic, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CoursesName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CoursesName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CoursesName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

[Tutorial data has a null foreign key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5dAl.png)

So i have been trying this while waiting for any help. I came up with this

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Tutorial Tutorial)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Tutorials.Add(new Tutorial {
                UserId = user.Id//i get the current user id but i cant insert it with the other data
            });

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(Tutorial);
    }
```

and i changed my models like this
**IdentityModels**
i put the virtual

```
public virtual ICollection<Tutorial> Tutorials { get; set; }
```

**Tutorial model**

```
   [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

**Create View**

```html
<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Tutorial</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Topic, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Topic, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Topic, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CoursesName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CoursesName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CoursesName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User.Id)*@

    @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, "UserId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("UserId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

but i get this error

```html
> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException
  HResult=0x80131920
  Message=Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at KLUE_Inc.Controllers.TutorialController.Create(Tutorial Tutorial) in C:\Users\raliq\Music\KLUE Inc\KLUE Inc\Controllers\TutorialController.cs:line 40
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

Comment: Its null because you have not set it. You need to set it in the POST method (based on the current user) before you add it to the context and save (but your model should have a navigation property for the UserID, and your `User` property should be marked as virtual

Comment: like public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
       public virtual ICollection<Tutorial> Tutorials { get; set; }
} and Tutorial model  [ForeignKey("User")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }. but how to set the current UserId in the post method please help because  am struggling with that

Comment: AspNet Identity should include an extension method to get the currently logged in user.  In your controller action, you can: `User.Identity.GetUserId()`.  In your code sample you are creating a new instance which will not have a valid userid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello i found the answer

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Tutorial tutorial)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        Tutorial.UserId = UserId;
        db.Tutorials.Add(tutorial);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(tutorial);
}
```

at first i was putting this code: var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();out of the if(
ModelState.isvalid) and it did not work it was giving me a null refrence. I want to thank  [Brendan Green](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1567352/brendan-green),

[ahmed-abdi](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/members/ahmed-abdi2) and [pathan-faisal](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/members/pathan-faisal) for helping me thanks.